# Chrome.storage.local.set: can't set and push into array properly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome extension which has a feature to add strings from HTML form and store them in chrome storage. I want to push strings to one array, so every time I send a string from the form, it'll be added into the same array.

However, it doesn't store data correctly with my code.

```
document.getElementById('add-word-form').onsubmit = function(){

  chrome.storage.local.get({ words:[] }, function(items) {

    let newWord = document.getElementById('vocabulary').value;

    let nextWord = items.words.push(newWord);

    chrome.storage.local.set({ words:[nextWord] });

  });
}
```

I'm guessing that I'm doing something wrong with chrome.storage.local.get() too, because I receive only numbers not actual string on console.log with code below...

```
chrome.storage.local.get({ words:[] }, function(items) {

  console.log(items.words); // Array(1) // on first form submit
                            // [2] // on second attempt and same onwards

});
```

Could anyone see where I am doing wrong..?

Comment: push() returns an index, which is hardly useful here. Replace the last line with just chrome.storage.local.set(items);

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much @wOxxOm for the quick response and the answer. I really appreciate your help!